# Find or create with SequelizeJS

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I try to use the "findOrCreate" function of SequelizeJS but it doesn't work.

The variable "created" is "undefined", so I don't know why because it's a variable used by SequelizeJS...

```
for( var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++ ){
    global.db.Tag.findOrCreate({name: tags[i]}).success( function(tag, created){
        if( created ){
            global.db.PostTag.create({
                PostId: id,
                TagId: tag.id
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Which version are you using? I believe that change might not have been published to npm, so could you try using the latest version from github.com/sequelize/sequelize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Upgrading from 1.7.0-alpha2 to 2.0.0-alpha2 solved it.
Cheers

Answer (score 3):

For me the answer was changing my promise resolver from .then to a .spread. This has something to do with the format that Sequelize returns data.

```
for( var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++ ){
    global.db.Tag.findOrCreate({
        name: tags[i]
    }).spread( function(tag, created){
        if( created ){
            global.db.PostTag.create({
                PostId: id,
                TagId: tag.id
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is correct. `.spread` is the correct way for handling findOrCreate for anybody stumbling upon this quesiton. **From the sequelize docs:** *"By default, the function will return two arguments: an array of results, and a metadata object, containing number of affected rows etc. Use .spread to access the results."* http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html

Comment: Use can also just use `await` which gives you a two-element array, then deconstruct or grab element `[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
global.db.Tag.findOrCreate({
    where:{
        name: tags[i]
    }, 
    defaults: {
    //properties you want on create
    }
}).then( function(tag){
    var created  = tag[1];
    tag = tag[0]; //new or found
    if( created ){

    }
}).fail(function(err) {

});
```

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/Upgrading-to-2.0

Answer (score 0):

we had that problem yesterday and we were able to fix it:

```
Tag.findOrCreate({
     where: { condition: value },
     // in the event that it is not found
     defaults: { /* properties of the model to create */ }
 })
     .then(tag => res.send(tag))
     .catch(err => res.send(err))`
```

returns:

```
{
    {
        /* tagProperties */
    },
    /* true if the tag was created
       false if the tag was found */
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.